# Create Proxy Service which publishes/triggers a topic event and passes data

Tags: publish-subscribe, wso2-esb

I have an issue which I do not have an idea how to resolve it. I am on WSB2 ESB 4.9.0.

I am trying to call a topic through a proxy using an event. However this never call the proxy subscribed to it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="publishSubscribeTest" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable"
  transports="http https" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <target>
    <inSequence>
        <log level="custom">
        <property value="********************* START METHOD *********************" name="publishSubscribeTest"/>
      </log>

      <event topic="TestTopic"/>

      <log level="custom">
        <property value="********************* END METHOD *********************" name="publishSubscribeTest"/>
      </log>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence>
      <drop/>
    </outSequence>
    <faultSequence/>
  </target>
</proxy>
```

The topic has the following details:

```
Topic Name: TestTopic
Permissions Details: (Everyone has permission to subscribe and publish)
WS Subscription Details: Another custom proxy in WSO2 has been configured as WS Subscription Details.
```

So when first proxy calls the topic, it should call the proxy subscribed to that topic. However it is never called.

This is the proxy called by topic:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="proxyCalledByTopic" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable"
  transports="https http" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <target>
    <inSequence>
      <log level="custom">
        <property value="********************* START METHOD *********************" name="proxyCalledByTopic"/>
      </log>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence>
      <send/>
    </outSequence>
    <faultSequence/>
  </target>
</proxy>
```

So the log should be something like:

> publishSubscribeTest = ********************* END METHOD
>   ********************* proxyCalledByTopic = ********************* START METHOD ********************* publishSubscribeTest =
>   ********************* START METHOD *********************

However it is like:

> publishSubscribeTest = ********************* END METHOD
>   *********************  publishSubscribeTest = ********************* START METHOD *********************

So I understand that the proxy called by the topic in the subscription is not called.

Any suggestion? Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some try outs, the issue why the pub sub was not triggering the event was due to the fact that content-type header needs was not populated appropriately from the incoming request to the proxy service. The same can be achieved from setting  up an POST api.

Once the content-type header is populated with either of the below values, the pub/sub events started working.

```
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Type: application/xml
```

Sample Posts:
XML

```
POST /TriggerTopic HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.224.234.34:8280
Content-Type: application/xml
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: f60c206c-a38e-ed2d-46a0-b051304247be

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Dont forget me this weekend from postman via API</body>
</note>
```

Sample Post JSON

```
POST /TriggerTopic HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.224.234.34:8280
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 3453ddc5-a279-203a-fecf-38e81bd3ba8b

{"value":"some value"}
```